# How can I get the user directory of a computer in Java? Not the current working directory

Tags: java, directory

I'm trying to get the current user directory, where all of the users on the computer are saved, so I can save some details to this folder so it will apply to the whole computer instead of just the user area of the current user.

For example

System.getProperty("user.home")

returns C:\Users\CURRENT_USER

How can I get the "C:\Users"

Probably using substring or something using the index of the last slash? But help would be appreciated, can't seem to get it

Comment: You have to query the registry at key : HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\ and value : ProfilesDirectory . On a W7, a typical value is %SystemDrive%\Users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the index of the system property "user.name" in the home directory that you already have.  You would use [`lastIndexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%29) to get the position, and [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) to effectively remove the user name.  Then you can remove the resultant trailing backslash.